# Why we have both macrotask and microtask queues in js?

Tags: javascript, promise

I know about macrotasks (e.g. setTimeout, eventListeners callbacks), microtasks (e.g. promises, requestAnimationFrame, mutation observers callbacks) and v8 event loop.

Why it is not enough only one queue? What kind of problems motivated js/browser creators add another one?

Comment: Does `requestAnimationFrame` really count as a microtask?